# Grails command objects and input name values

Tags: grails, groovy, command-objects

I have a form where I have to have the input elements ordered specifically.  So my form looks something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="name"/>
<select name="contacts.first">...</select>
<select name="contacts.second">...</select>
...
```

I have a command object that I'm trying to use to validate this form.  However, I can't seem to get it to map correctly. My command object looks like this:

```
@Validatable
class MyCommand {
     def name
     def contacts

     static constraints = { /* ... */ }
}
```

My controller action looks like:

```
def update = { MyCommand cmd -> 
    if (cmd.validate()) {
         /* ... */
    }
}
```

When I look at `cmd.contacts`, it's null.  If I name each select just `contacts` instead of `contacts.first`, it is an array of values as expected, but I did not want to depend on the browser to make sure these items are in a specific order.  Any suggestions to making this work?  The correct order is crucial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original idea: http://stateyourbizness.blogspot.com/2009/02/binding-to-collection-fields-on-command.html

So for your command object you could use:

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.FactoryUtils;
import org.apache.commons.collections.ListUtils;

class MyCommand {
    def name
    List contacts = ListUtils.lazyList([], FactoryUtils.constantFactory(''))
    /* ... */
}
```

And have your html look like:

```
<input type="text" name="name"/>
<select name="contacts[0]">...</select>
<select name="contacts[1]">...</select>
```